# Prove a $gcd(x^a-1,x^b-1)=x^{gcd(a,b)}-1$ using knowledge of polynomials and not number theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Prove the following:
>
> 1. $U_n=\{Z \in \mathbb{C} : Z^n = 1\}$.  Then, show that $U_a \cap U_b = U_{gcd(a,b)}$
> 2. Hence prove that, $gcd(x^a-1,x^b-1)=x^{gcd(a,b)}-1$

I started out with if $α \in U_a$, then $α = e^{\frac{2ikπ}a}$ where $0<k<a$  and if $β \in U_b$, then $β = e^{\frac{2ilπ}b}$ where $0<l<b$.  So, if $α=β$, then $e^{\frac{2ikπ}a}=e^{\frac{2ilπ}b}$
$\implies \frac kl=\frac ba$

Then i claimed that : For every $k, 0<k<gcd(a,b)$, we find $l$ such that $\frac kl=\frac ba$

But then I am not able to prove my claim. Please help me.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1?noredirect=1&lq=1) has really many answers. I suppose there is one, which you can use.

Comment: I am not getting an answer by using the first part and that is what I want.

Comment: The first part is the above duplicate, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2453328/for-alpha-in-mathbbt-prove-that-alpham-1-and-alphan-1-only-if?rq=1).

Comment: See the "alternative" argument using "order" in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/7561/242) in the linked dupe.